# Tabbar is not showing OR screen does not reconize touches

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

i'm using this code for a tabbar, but the tabbar is not showing

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,
                                     viewController2,
                                     viewController3,
                                     viewController4, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;



    UIViewController *rootController = 
    [[xTableViewController alloc] 
     initWithNibName:@"xTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                            initWithRootViewController:rootController];


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] 
                   initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

When i remove this line:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] 
                       initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

The tabbar show's up but i cant 'touch' my screen (i cant touch my screen but the tabbar is 'touchable' because nothing is working, does anyone know how to display the tabbar on a normal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are initializing the window twice. First with the UITabbarContorller and then with UINavigationController. Try

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,
                                 viewController2,
                                 viewController3,
                                 viewController4, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the it's not displaying 'xTableViewController'

Comment: you said you needed tabbar displayed. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to have xTableViewController displayed and the tabar, then put the xTableViewController inside the tabbar, just like you did with i.e viewController1

Comment: xTableViewController is an tableview that is need to be displayed. I just wanted a tabbar inside it but with the code in my first post i can't touch the tableview.

Comment: why would you put the tabbar inside the tableview? that's not a good idea. You should put this xTableView indside the tabbarController, to make it work properly(as a result you will have a tableview displayed with the tab bar in the bottom) Check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html for reference.